# How to get IPv6 of a website?

Tags: windows-8.1, ping, ipv6

How can I get the IPv6 address of any website ( eg www.google.com) using ping command in cmd on windows 8.1? And is it possible to do so if my OS only supports link-local IPv6?
I tried this: `ping -6 www.google.com` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `nslookup` like you normally would. If the site has an IPv6 address it will be returned in the list:

```
nslookup google.com

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  
          2607:f8b0:400a:804::1005
          173.194.33.166
          173.194.33.174
          173.194.33.165
          173.194.33.162
          173.194.33.164
          173.194.33.169
          173.194.33.163
          173.194.33.160
          173.194.33.161
          173.194.33.168
          173.194.33.167
```

If you want to *only* return the IPv6 address (if present), you can use `nslookup -query=AAAA`:

```
nslookup -query=AAAA google.com

Name:    google.com
Address:  2607:f8b0:400a:804::1005
```

Keep in mind that `ping` is not designed to be used as a lookup tool. In order to ping something the computer must do a lookup, and does end up showing you an IP address, but if your purpose is to find an IP address it makes more sense to just use `nslookup` directly. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Thanks! Your method works perfectly. But here I got confused somehow. You said that `nslookup` is used by `ping` yet I still can't ping Google's IPv6 address, so what's going on?

Comment: @mhmdhsenkamal `ping` doesn't use `nslookup` directly, but it does basically the same thing internally. In order to `ping` something you need to know its IP address. And in order to find an IP address, you must do a nameserver lookup. However, a nameserver lookup can return an IP address which you might not be able to ping.

Comment: An NSlookup is like looking somebody up in an address book. You get their address, but just because you know the address doesn't mean that if you go to their house their door will be open.